# SonarQube 7.9.1 not able to scan .cs and sql files for .net project running through Jenkins

Tags: .net, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I have SonarQube version 7.9.1 and I am running sonar scan through Jenkins. It scans all the files but is unable to scan .cs and sql files for my MS project. How can I resolve this issue?

sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=MSProject
sonar.projectName=MSProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Enable the Visual Studio bootstrapper
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true

# Language
sonar.language=cs

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources= .

# Encoding of sources files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Also, I can see some warnings in Jenkins logs from where I am running sonarscanner. Not sure though IF it is related.

```
WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.
```

I am using sonar scanner version 2.6.1

This is how I am running sonnarscanner in my pipeline script

```
/home/sonar/sonar-scanner-2.2.1/bin/sonar-scanner
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [SonarScanner for .NET](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) to analyze C# projects.

Comment: Hi @duncanp, I have added SonnarScanner for MSBuild in jenkins, can you please help how to run it through pipeline script

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about Jenkins. However, there is also a SonarScanner for Jenkins that should simplify calling the scanner. See the docs for more info: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have gone through the document bit confusing for me whether dotnet core needs to be installed or just SonarScanner for MSBuild will do the work